# External users unable to register in community application portal

Tags: community

I am getting the below error when trying to register as an external user on community application (EASY App by Maryville University) we have -

Application_Portal has reached the available portal license limit. Registration from Application Portal are not able to create portal users.

Can someone guide me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Salesforce environment that has this portal app that you are using has ran out of the Salesforce portal or community license.

The fastest way to resolve this would be reach out the company that provides portal with the error you are getting and they allocate a license from the backend or purchase a license so you can register.

Comment: are portal licenses different from community licenses? cuz I'm pretty sure have community licences ..

Comment: They are different. I suggest you look into what license is getting assigned when a new user is created .Sounds like it might be the portal one or a license that's no more available is assigned.You can also check company profile to see what license available is 0 now

Comment: Thanks, I checked this very thing by going to workspace --> Administration --> login and registration --> registration page configuration --> assign users to a profile and account --> ('Customer Community Login User') is selected in the drop down. So this mean the new user should get assigned to community license and not portal license right?

Comment: That's correct ! Check also company profile to see license count ?